# How to "select distinct" across multiple data frame columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates, distinct

I'm looking for a way to do the equivalent to the SQL

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2 FROM dataframe_table
```

The pandas sql comparison doesn't have anything about `distinct`.

`.unique()` only works for a single column, so I suppose I could concat the columns, or put them in a list/tuple and compare that way, but this seems like something pandas should do in a more native way.

Am I missing something obvious, or is there no way to do this?

Comment: You'd have to do something like `df.apply(pd.Series.unique)` but this won't work if the number of unique values varies across the columns so you'd have to construct a dict of the column names as keys and the unique values as the values

Comment: [SO Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/pandas/1751/indexing-and-selecting-data/26077/select-distinct-rows-across-dataframe)

Answer (score 306, accepted):

You can use the [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) method to get the unique rows in a DataFrame:

```
In [29]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,1,2], 'b':[3,4,3,5]})

In [30]: df
Out[30]:
   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  4
2  1  3
3  2  5

In [32]: df.drop_duplicates()
Out[32]:
   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  4
3  2  5
```

You can also provide the `subset` keyword argument if you only want to use certain columns to determine uniqueness. See the [docstring](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html).

Comment: Possibly worth noting that `df.drop_duplicates()` by default is not an inplace method, so returns a new DataFrame (leaving `df` unchanged). This is fairly standard behaviour, but may still be useful point out.

Answer (score 39):

I've tried different solutions. First was:

```
a_df=np.unique(df[['col1','col2']], axis=0)
```

and it works well for non-object data.

Another way to do this and to avoid error (for object columns type) is to apply `drop_duplicates()`:

```
a_df=df.drop_duplicates(['col1','col2'])[['col1','col2']]
```

You can also use SQL to do this, but it worked very slow in my case:

```
from pandasql import sqldf
q = """SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2 FROM df;"""
pysqldf = lambda q: sqldf(q, globals())
a_df = pysqldf(q)
```

Answer (score 13):

To solve a similar problem, I'm using `groupby`:

```
print(f"Distinct entries: {len(df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']))}")
```

Whether that's appropriate will depend on what you want to do with the result, though (in my case, I just wanted the equivalent of `COUNT DISTINCT` as shown).

Answer (score 10):

I think use `drop duplicate` sometimes will not be so useful depending dataframe.

I found this:

```
[in] df['col_1'].unique()
[out] array(['A', 'B', 'C'], dtype=object)
```

And worked for me!

https://riptutorial.com/pandas/example/26077/select-distinct-rows-across-dataframe

Answer (score 9):

There is no `unique` method for a df, if the number of unique values for each column were the same then the following would work: `df.apply(pd.Series.unique)` but if not then you will get an error. Another approach would be to store the values in a dict which is keyed on the column name:

```
In [111]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,2,2,4], 'b':[1,1,1,2,2]})
d={}
for col in df:
    d[col] = df[col].unique()
d

Out[111]:
{'a': array([0, 1, 2, 4], dtype=int64), 'b': array([1, 2], dtype=int64)}
```

Comment: is it possible to check for unique for multiple columns ?

Comment: Got the answer from another SO question using numpy `np.unique(df[['column1','column2']].values)`

Answer (score 2):

I think the following is the cleanest approach:

```
df.filter(items=['Column A', 'Column B']).drop_duplicates()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take the sets of the columns and just subtract the smaller set from the larger set:

```
distinct_values = set(df['a'])-set(df['b'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled onto this question looking for the same solution but using Apache Spark for .NET (C#).

The following worked for me (given a list of CSV files in a folder):

```
string filePath = "file:///Users/me/dups/*";

var opts = new Dictionary<string, string>();
opts.Add("header", "true");
opts.Add("quote", "\"");
opts.Add("multiLine", "true");
opts.Add("sep", ",");

// load data
DataFrame df1 = spark.Read()
   .Options(opts)
   .Csv(filePath);

// columns to distinct on. in my case, there was 1 column I knew that was distinct per row so I listed all columns below minus that one.
Column[] columns = {
    Col("MyColumn1"),
    Col("MyColumn2"),
    // etc.
};

var distinctCount = df1
    .Select(columns)
    .Distinct()
    .Count();

Console.WriteLine(distinctCount);
```